# How can I redirect HTTP to HTTPS with a local self assigned SSL certificate in my .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, https

I'm having trouble redirecting HTTP to HTTPS with a self assigned SSL certificate generated by MAMP PRO using the following code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I have also tried the [patrol](https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.patrol) plugin for Craft, enabling/disabling dev mode and included  `'enableCsrfProtection' => true,` in my `general.php`

Also the .htaccess [provided by Craft](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/force-ssl) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

(You were missing the `=` sign.)

For more info, see our help article, [How do I force SSL for CP requests?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/force-ssl)

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately adding the `=` sign doesn't resolve the issue. I've tried several approaches but none seem to work. I'm guessing that the problem lies elsewhere. Perhaps it's my MAMP PRO Apache configuration.

Comment: @hascoulijn Can you add those `[NC,R=301,L]` flags to the end of the `RewriteRule` line, like the help article has?

Comment: I was using the exact code from the help article but it didn't work. But it looks like my `http` and `https` connections are treated like separate domains since the `http` completely ignores the `.htacces` while the `https` connection returns an Internal Server Error after inserting some junk value.

Comment: @hascoulijn In that case you should talk to your host. They may be doing something non-standard and have some advice on how to do this.

Comment: Ultimately the [help article](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/force-ssl) and your answer were the solution, I just had to figure out how to successfully set up SSL with MAMP first.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by duplicating my host in MAMP PRO without SSL checked, this has to do with the different ports being used for `http` and `https` by Apache. So I now have

```
example.dev
example.dev with SSL enabled
```

`http` now redirects to `https` using the code from [How do I force SSL for CP requests](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/force-ssl).